# Dynamic SQL within cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My dynamic sql below to alter a table & create columns based on the output of a query is giving error.

Query :

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1 is select distinct WP_NO from temp;
   cnum VARCHAR2(255);

BEGIN

  FOR cnum in c1 
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Alter table temp_col add (:1 varchar2(255))' using cnum;
  END LOOP;  

  COMMIT;

END;
```

Error :

> PLS-00457: expressions have to be of SQL types

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because [bind variables are not allowed in DDL statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489002/why-cannot-i-use-bind-variables-in-ddl-scl-statements-in-dynamic-sql/25489003#25489003).

Consider trying it without using the bind variable:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 is select distinct WP_NO from temp;
  cnum VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
  FOR cnum in c1 
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Alter table temp_col add ('|| cnum ||' varchar2(255))';
  END LOOP;  

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: exactly. Bind variables are not allowed everywhere.

Comment: Depending on the source of `temp.WP_NO` aka `cnum`, you may want to sanitize it to protect against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score -1):

You have a conflict with the *cnum* symbol, which you use both as a local variable and for the current row of the cursor.

You probably want this:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1 is select distinct WP_NO from temp;

BEGIN

  FOR current_row in c1 
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Alter table temp_col add (:1 varchar2(255))' using current_row.WP_NO;
  END LOOP;  

  COMMIT;

END;
```

As you can see, you don't need to declare the *current_row* variable that you use in the for loop.

Comment: Bind variables cannot be used here.

Comment: Both the answers did not work (though OMG ponies was right about the bind variables). The correct solution is :


begin

   FOR x in (select distinct WP_NO 
               from temp) loop

     execute immediate 'alter table temp_col add  '|| x.wp_no || ' varchar2(255)'; 
   
   END LOOP; 
 
END;