# Execute Immediate bind variable

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, dynamicquery, bind-variables

I have the following function that calculates content of the table but when I pass any param it throws:

```
EXEC DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(get_size('employees'))
Error report -
ORA-00903: invalid table name
ORA-06512: at "HR.GET_SIZE", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1
00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"
```

**Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_size(v_table_name IN VARCHAR2) 
   RETURN NUMBER IS total_size NUMBER(16);
   plsql_statement VARCHAR2(500) := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  :param';
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_statement INTO total_size USING v_table_name;
    RETURN(total_size); 
END;
/


EXEC DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(get_size('employees'));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why cannot I use bind variables in DDL/SCL statements in dynamic SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489002/why-cannot-i-use-bind-variables-in-ddl-scl-statements-in-dynamic-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't [bind table names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25489003/92837), it needs to be constructed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_size(v_table_name IN VARCHAR2) 
   RETURN NUMBER IS total_size NUMBER(16);
   plsql_statement VARCHAR2(500)
BEGIN
    plsql_statement := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  ' || v_table_name;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_statement INTO total_size;
    RETURN(total_size); 
END;
/


EXEC DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(get_size('employees'));
```

Comment: `USING v_table_name` are you sure?

Comment: missed correcting that one when pasted from question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind table names or column names. You can bind only variables.

In your case, you just need to **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** the dynamic SQL.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_size(v_table_name IN VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN NUMBER IS total_size NUMBER(16);
  3     plsql_statement VARCHAR2(500);
  4  BEGIN
  5      plsql_statement := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  ' || v_table_name;
  6      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_statement INTO total_size;
  7      RETURN(total_size);
  8  END;
  9  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> EXEC DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(get_size('EMP'));
14

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```