# create any table name with prepareStatement jdbc java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

So I'm trying to create an unspecified table name with an unspecified columns, however, I'm new to prepareStatement and I'm not exactly sure what to do.
This is how I'm thinking about it
I know I'll need a loop for multiple entries of "line" which is the table name
but how can I deal with the columns? I think I'm specifying the number of columns in here (4). How can I do this without specifying? and what should I put for setString if the value will differ based on the table name?
I'm kind of confused and I was hoping that someone will explain this to me

```
loop start ....
line = kb.next();
sql = "Create TABLE " + line  + "(?,?,?,?)";
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1,?);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
loop end
```

Comment: Prepared statement placeholders can only be used in places where SQL allows expressions. Column names in a `CREATE TABLE` statement are not expressions. You need to use string concatenation for this.

Comment: also, mysql is not fond of `create table 1 (id int);` but will accept that tablename wrapped in back-ticks

Comment: Don't use a prepared statement. It's the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely that you'll be able to get this to work on any database.

For Oracle-specific reasoning, see [Why cannot I use bind variables in DDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25489003/2540382)

Comment: Do you mean that the "?,?" itself won't work using create? or are you talking about the preparestatement?

Comment: Correct. "?" are bind variables, and they won't work. You can definitely issue a CREATE TABLE statement in a PreparedStatement.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, now it makes a lot of sense